# Need to populate new field based on existing data

Tags: craft3, database, field

Say I have a section called "Stores" that has an existing field called "Store Hours". The client has populated the store hours for 1000 some stores. Now, however, it seems what the client really wants is the ability to quickly see which stores are open on Sunday. So now I need to add a new field called "Open Sunday" and correctly filly its value for each store based on its existing hours.

What I've tried:
I've added a new field, and then wrote SQL to update the contents table to fill out the value of "Open Sunday" based on the "Store Hours", however, I need to manually re-save entries in order for my frontend queries to see the new "Open Sunday" value. Editing contents directly doesnt seem to let Craft know that the new field has a new value (possibly its saved in revisions or versions?).

*This example is just that, an example. I do not need twig snippets in how I can derive what stores are open on Sunday from a story hours field.

Comment: What field type is store hours? Can you add a screenshot of an example entry?

Comment: The new field type is a radio button. The old field type was checkboxes